# TF DIR command to list all folders that match a name

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to use the `tf dir` command to walk a server tree and list all of the absolute folder locations which match a specific name string?

I can use `tf dir /recursive /folders` and this will recursively walk the tree, but I cannot figure out how (if it is possible) to apply a filter on the command.  From the looks of the [help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6320xzye.aspx), the `tf dir` command takes an *itemspec*, but I can't seem to find in the MSDN help what this exactly means or a list of qualifiers.

Example: I want to list the path of all folders with a folder named 'Prod' somewhere in their path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a wildcard directory path with **TF DIR** as follows:

*Scenario tested against TFS 2015 Update 1 installed server-side and Visual 2015 update 1 installed client-side.*

```
tf dir /folders $/<PROJECT_NAME>/*Prod /recursive /collection:https://<HOST_NAME>/tfs/<COLLECTION_NAME>
```

Note: The command does not support wildcarding the **PROJECT_NAME** in the command above, if you try wildcarding the **PROJECT_NAME** the command will return the following response:

> TF402396: You cannot include wildcard characters in a team project
>   name.

Additional notes: the reason why I did not specify credentials is because my creds are cached on my local machine. If you need to specify creds you can do so by adding the following argument:

```
/login:<DOMAIN\USERNAME>,<PASSWORD>
```

[tf dir - reference documentation @msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6320xzye(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: I also determined that the single character `?` wildcard identifier is also supported.

Comment: Thanks for the variation.